# Sorting with comparable (Java)

Tags: java, sorting, comparable

I've implemented the interface comparable and the method compareTo(). I have a list named randomHumans that contains 10 objects. 5 objects with three fields: name, age and year they started studying, and 5 objects with two fields: name and age. I would like to sort my list, and tried using:

```
Collections.sort(randomHumans);
```

This gave me the following error message:

`The method sort(List<T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<Object>)`

I then tried this code:

```
Collections.sort((List<T>) randomObjects);
```

But it just gives me two new error messages. Maybe I need to specify what field it should sort after, but I can't find how to implement this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**`main` method:**

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Object> randomObjects = new ArrayList<Object>();
    for (int j=0; j<5; j++) {
        Fysiker randomFysiker = new Fysiker();
        randomObjects.add(randomFysiker);

        Human randomHuman = new Human();
        randomObjects.add(randomHuman);
    }
    System.out.println(randomObjects.toString());

    //Collections.sort(randomObjects);
}
```

**`Human` class:**

```
class Human implements Comparable<Human> {

    int age;
    String name;

    public Human (int myAge, String myName) {
        name = myName;
        age = myAge;

    }

    public Human() {
        this(randomAge(),randomName());

    }

    public int compareTo(Human o) {
        return this.age - o.age;

    }

    protected static int randomAge() {
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();

        return randomGenerator.nextInt(100);

    }

    protected static String randomName() {
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();

        return "Name"+randomGenerator.nextInt(15);

    }

    public int getAge(){
        return age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "\nName: " + name + "\nAge: " + age + " yrs old\n";
    }


}
```

**`Fysiker` class:**

```
public class Fysiker extends Human {

    int year;

    public Fysiker(int myAge2, String myName2, int myYear) {

        name = myName2;
        year = myYear+1932;

        if (myAge2 >= 15+(2017-myYear)) {
            age = myAge2;   
        } else {
            age = 15+(2017-year);
        }
    }

    public Fysiker() {
        this(randomAge(),randomName(), randomYear());
    }

    protected static int randomYear() {
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();

        return randomGenerator.nextInt(83);
    }

    public int getYear(){
        return year;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "\nName: " + name + "\nAge: " + age + " yrs old" + "\nStarted Physics: " + year+"\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the type of `randomHumans`

Comment: `randomHumans` is of type Objects, and containts 2 or 3 fields depending on if it's a "Human" or a "Student" class. Every even object is a Human and every odd object is a Student.

Comment: @armara (I assume) what Ramanlfc meant was, please show exactly how you defined `randomHumans`

Comment: Can't you just replace your description of randomHumans with the class definitions of `Student` and `Human`?

Comment: what is a `Fysiker`?

Comment: I updated my main post so it includes my code, where `Student` = `Fysiker`. My class `Fysiker` is not showed in my code, but it extends the Human class and adds a third "year" field which states which year he/she started studying.

Comment: You cannot sort a list of `Object`, because it doesn't implement `Comparable`. You already let `Human` implement `Comparable`, so why don't just write `ArrayList<Human>`? Is `Fysiker` also a `Human`?

Comment: does `Fysiker` extend `Human` ?

Comment: Yes, `Fysiker` extends `Human`. See edited post if you would like to see how the `Fysiker` class looks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the generic parameter from `Object` to `Human`

```
public static void main (String[] args) {

    List<Human> randomObjects = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {

        Fysiker randomFysiker = new Fysiker();
        randomObjects.add(randomFysiker);

        Human randomHuman = new Human();
        randomObjects.add(randomHuman);
    }
    System.out.println(randomObjects);

    Collections.sort(randomObjects);
}
```

Comment: thanks, this worked! I dont understand why though. It's creating a list of only `Human`, but there's both `Human` and `Fysiker` in it. Does it always work like this? If I declare the lists variables as `Human` instead of `Object`, it works for any class?

Comment: Well, thats the same as saying that `List<Object>` should not accept any `Human`s, as they are of type `Human`. In fact, if something requires an object, you can pass anything that inherits from `Object` (all classes inherit from `Object`). So just like a `List<Object>` can contain a `Human`, so can a `List<Human>` contain a `Student`

Answer (score 1):

When you write `Collections.sort(randomHumans);` `randomHumans` must be a List of Comparable. If you are 'forced' to use a List of Object, you must give a `Comparator` to explain how to compare each object :

```
Collections.sort(randomHumans, humanComparator);
```

It's all explained in the offcial documentation :

- [`sort(java.util.List)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List))
- [`sort(java.util.List, java.util.Comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator))